# Docker - access another container on the same machine via its public ip, without docker links

Tags: networking, docker

On a VPS with a static, publicly routable IP, I have a simple web server running (on port 8080) in a container that exports port 8080 (`-p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080`).

If I spin up another container on the same box and try to `curl <public ip of host>:8080` it resolves the address, tries to connect but fails when making the request (it just hangs).

From the host's shell (outside containers), `curl <public ip of host>:8080` succeeds.

Why is this happening? My feeling is that, somehow, the virtual network cards fail to communicate with each other. Is there a workaround (besides using docker links)?

Answer (score 2):

According to Docker's advanced networking docs (http://docs.docker.io/use/networking/): "Docker uses iptables under the hood to either accept or drop communication between containers."

As such, I believe you would need to setup inbound and outbound routing with iptables.  This article gives a solid description of how to do so: http://blog.codeaholics.org/2013/giving-dockerlxc-containers-a-routable-ip-address/